# Eclipse displays nothing(see screenshot) when i open my workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

Eclipse displays nothing(see screenshot)  when i open my workspace, however it properly loads other workspaces

Comment: It means that your workspace is corrupt. I have a zip copy of my workspace and I use (decompress it in place) it for restoring it in case of emergency.

Comment: How do i solve this ? i have searched for solutions and they asked me to delete .snap file from org.eclipse.core.resources in plugins folder of the workspace, but doesnt seem to work

Comment: If you have no backup of the `.metadata` folder... then re-import all your projects one at a time. I presume you have a backup of your projects, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following step :

1. Copy project folder and lib folder(if lib is exist)
2. delete workspace
3. Now open eclipse and create new workspace.
4. Import your existing project to that workspace.